# Office 2010 64-bit PIAs

Tags: visual-studio, office-interop, office-pia

I have a Windows 8 machine with VS 2010, VS 2012 and Office 2013 64-bit installed.

We have a large VS 2010, Excel 2010 add-in template project that we are able to run and debug fine on a machine with Office 2010/2013 32-bit. However on this machine with Office 2013 64-bit, we get a COMException saying:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {62F8CCF6-3C71-11D2-8B38-00A0C970A730} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I ensured the project is built for 64-bit architecture.

We had installed Office 2010 PIA (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=3508) on this machine after which we are able to build and run the Excel add-in project but it generates the COMException at run-time.

We created another Excel 2013 template add-in project using VS 2012 and we are able to build, deploy and debug it just fine in Offce 2013 64-bit.

So on this setup, what can be done to make the Offce 2010 template project debuggable in VS 2010/2012.

Comment: Not posting the full exception message is a big, big mistake.  Might not mean anything to you, it means lots to us.

Comment: I am very soory @HansPassant, I have added the exact error message now.

Answer (score 1):

> Office 2010 64-bit PIAs

There is no such PIAs. They are not platform specific.

> the project is built for 64-bit architecture.

There is no need to change the target platform of the add-in. You should keep it set to the AnyCPU value unless you use a platform specific components.

> we get a COMException saying, Cannot find a class with Id.... I

Could you be more specific? What class are you talking about?

Anyway, due to the fact that you can run a newly created add-in project, the issue depends on your project and not relatedo to VSTO or PIAs.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your reply. I am sorry and have updated the exact COMException now. I am trying to figure out, but would VS 2010 vs VS 2012 and Excel 2010 template vs Excel 2013 template make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

That guid belongs to iManage rather than Office:

```
namespace Com.Interwoven.Worksite.iManExt;

[ComImport]
[Guid("62F8CCF6-3C71-11D2-8B38-00A0C970A730")]
[ClassInterface(0)]
[DefaultMember("Item")]
[TypeLibType(2)]
public class ContextItemsClass : IContextItems, ContextItems, IEnumerable
{
    . . .
```